# Value of the first element of a multidimentional int global array gets strange number when it's accessed c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, variables, global

I am getting this strange problem and couldn't figure out the reason.

The same code was use in several programs. This problem only happens in one of them. And I cannot depulicate the problem in a simplified test program. The problem happens only to the first element of the array.

```
int arrX[30]; // arrX is declared extern int arrX[30] somewhere else

class Y {
   void calculateX(int a) {
      int z = 0, i = 0;
      while (i < 50) {
         z += (i * a); // some calculation here
         ++i;
      }
      enterlock(lockx); 
      // here is some lock to make sure arrX will not be modified at the same time
      if (arrX[a] != z) arrX[a] = z; 
      exitlock(lockx);
     // if a = 0, in most times when the program runs to the comparison above, 
     // value of arrX changes to something like 1159200338 and the value stays  
     // there even after the value of z is assigned to it. The next time when code  
     // access arrX[0] here the value may change to 1159200276. only sometimes 
     // it's value is set to that of z.
   }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like there could be some other array in memory that is being accessed out of bounds. One way to track this is with your debugger and a breakpoint that triggers when a particular memory location is written to.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Also, you should use assertions or exceptions to validate any assumption you make.